# \item right align label

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem

I have a document for a CV with a list, and I would like to right align the labels. I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360191/description-list-aligned-right), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445066/enumitem-right-align-the-label) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels), but I can't make it work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\usepackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{\bfseries\scshape\Huge{Title}}
    \begin{cvlist}{}
        \item[Some label] Some text.\\
        \item[Some label] Some text.\\
    \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using MacTex. Any idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a CV there are special document classes, e.g. moderncv. Here is the right aligned list already provided.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual} % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}  % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\firstname{YourFirstName}
\familyname{YourFamilyName}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\sectionfont \Huge CV
\end{flushright}

\section{Experience}
\cvitem{2018}{Some short number}
\cvitem{2000--2018}{some longer number}
\end{document}
```

For more information please have a look here [CTAN: Paket moderncv](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)

Comment: I'm using `currvita`, I think is different from `moderncv`